# RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored

Tags: mod-rewrite

Following is my `.htaccess`. It works good, but I got an error in `error_log` file:

> [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' 
>              is not supported and will be ignored.

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^part_(\d+)$        /detail.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^find_(.+)$     /search.php?q=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this helps, but according to this [website](http://www.my-whiteboard.com/how-to-install-open-source-ecommerce-magento-software-and-php-52-on-centos-5-linux/), if you see the following error in Apache error log:

```
[warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern ‘-f’ is not 
       supported and will be ignored
```

You should change the following line in your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Note the missing `[NC]` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this message when I used the stock .htaccess file with a Simple Scripts Joomla 2.5.1 install on bluehost. I fixed it be commenting out the symbolic link directive as suggested in the htaccess file:

```
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
```