# RewriteRules not load some of css. js and images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

At the moment, I'm having trouble with loading some of css, js and image files when I use RewriteRules to rewrite my URLs.

Contents of my `.htaccess` are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?newstype=$1&newsid=$2&newstitle=$3 [L,QSA,NC,B]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

    # RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/?$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Here is the structure of my site:

```
[root]
  css
    vender
      bootstrap.css
    plugin
      plugin.css
    style.css
  js
    vender
      bootstrap.js
    plugin
      plugin.js
    main.js
  images
    sliders
      slider1.jpg
      slider2.jpg
    1.jpg
    2.jgp
  index.php
  .htaccess
```

This is how I load my `JS` and `CSS` files:

```
/css/style.css
/css/vender/bootstrap.css
/css/plugin/plugin.css

/js/main.js
/js/vender/bootstrap.js
/js/plugin/plugin.js
```

Its load only `style.css` file and `main.js` files. Can anybody tell me, what is problem to not load other files which are inside a sub folder?

If I comment this line `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?newstype=$1&newsid=$2&newstitle=$3 [L,QSA,NC,B]`, then every thing is working nicely.

I also tried changing relative path to absolute and adding `<base href="/">` inbetween the `<head>` `</head>` tags. But either doesn’t work for me.

Hope somebody may help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess Rules file.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.
Basically we need to place your rewrite rule for news.php under other rewrite rule.

Also making sure to disable `MultiViews` functionality in rules to make sure only exact contents are being found.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?newstype=$1&newsid=$2&newstitle=$3 [L,QSA,NC,B]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, Its working. I never thought rules order would be the issue.. May I know these two lines are needed? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: @user3733831, those lines are making sure this rules only gets executed when request is for non-existing pages else it wouldn't be touched/executed. Let me know if any other clarification is needed here too, cheers.

Comment: Sir one more thing. Just I found my rewrite rule is not working. Its going to `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: @user3733831, which rule for which sample url is not working? kindly do mention.

Comment: This one `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?newstype=$1&newsid=$2&newstitle=$3 [L,QSA,NC,B]`

Comment: Sir, If I remove this lines then its working `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: @user3733831, these rules should work. Kindly do let me know what sample url you are using/hitting and getting error?

Comment: @user3733831, sorry I can't join chat room. Could you please do ping here itself in comments

Comment: These are the error messages from apache error.log file:

Comment: AH00665: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.

Comment: Other one is `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: @user3733831, please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8734653/5866580 for your above shown error once.

Comment: @user3733831, Do you have any other rules apart from these 2 sets in your htaccess fle?

Comment: No.. not at the moment

Comment: @user3733831, ok, please try edited rules now, Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Ok thank you, let me check it now

Comment: Sir, Now its working... Sir can I know if adding a new rule in the future will be a problem?

Comment: @user3733831, no these rules should be fine IMHO cheers.

Comment: Sorry sir, you have to spend more time helping me. Your support is greatly appreciated.